# How to show related category posts in side bar when someone click on the post in WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Hello WordPress developers, When a user click on a post so in sidebar all posts should be show to that related category at which the user has clicked ( Not on category but on post). 
I want this feature for my own website please help me. 
My Website link: www.unicodea.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to display a list of the categories a post belongs to is with `the_category()`. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

If you want to print the categories in your own custom way, then you can simply fetch them with `get_the_category()` and do what you want to do with them. `get_the_category()` can also be used outside the main loop by passing in the post's id.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/